# Calculate rank of user based on JSON array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below JSON array. I want to give rank based on number of entries of user. Here srjahir32@gmail.com will get 1st rank because it has 3 entries. other will get 2nd and 3rd respectively based on number of entries.

```js
let data = [{
    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "bspilak@cooperequipment.ca"
  },
  {
    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"
  }
]

function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
  const map = new Map();
  list.forEach((item) => {
    const key = keyGetter(item);
    if (!map.has(key)) {
      map.set(key, [item]);
    } else {
      map.get(key).push(item);
    }
  });
  return map;
}

var grouped = groupBy(data, a => a.email);
console.log(grouped);
```

You see my code to calculate numebr of entries by user. It gives me total entries but I'm not sure how to calculate rank.

Above code gives me grouped by values. But it does not help me to count rank. 
Output should just rank of user. like 1, 2 or 3.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/pbaw55nk/)

Comment: Please share a working snippet.

Comment: Your code returns an empty object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/pbaw55nk/

Comment: what should happen with same count? should they get the same rank?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, Your solution is giving rank inversely. Hight number or records gets last rank.

Comment: that is another problem i do not understand, hight count gives low rank? what happens if you have one with three counts and two with two. does the two with two gets the same rank? and which one?

Comment: @NinaScholz If user has 3 entries, he will get 1st rank means 1. If 2 users has 2 entries. They both will get rank 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions `reduce` and `sort`

```js
var array = [ {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"}, {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"}, {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"}, {"email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"}, {"email": "bspilak@cooperequipment.ca"}, {"email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"}];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
  (a[c.email] || (a[c.email] = {email: c.email, rank: 0})).rank++;
  return a;
}, {})).sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank);
result.forEach((r, i) => r.rank = i + 1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's perfect answer

Comment: actually its not. You are giving rank based on order. I needed rank based on number of entries.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for that.

You only need to setup an `accumulator` that will contain every email as a `key` and the number of occurences of said email as a `value`.

```js
let arr = [
 {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"},
 {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"},
 {"email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"},
 {"email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"},
 {"email": "bspilak@cooperequipment.ca"},
 {"email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"}
];

let ranking = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc[curr.email]) acc[curr.email]++;
  else acc[curr.email] = 1;
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(ranking);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could count the occurences and sort the result by the count.

```js
function groupBy(list, key) {
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach(item => map.set(item[key], (map.get(item[key]) || 0) + 1));
    return [...map]
        .sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) => a - b)
        .map((rank => (item, i, a) => ({ [key]: item[0], rank: (a[i - 1] || [])[1] === item[1] ? rank : ++rank }))(0));
}

var data = [{ email: "3@gmail.com" }, { email: "3@gmail.com" }, { email: "3@gmail.com" }, { email: "2@gmail.com" }, { email: "2@cooperequipment.ca" }, { email: "2@cooperequipment.ca" }, { email: "2@gmail.com" }],
    grouped = groupBy(data,'email');

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: How do i access rank ?

Comment: you could access the ranky by using the index. rank one is on index `0`, rank two is on index `1` and so on.